# Access a Class Property in Java

Tags: class, spring-mvc, properties

In my spring MVC project, I have a JSP which has fields like firstName, LastName etc. In the controller class, I pass Person class as Model Attribute and feed the properties with the corresponding fields.

My question is how do I access those properties in another controller. If I declare

```
Person person = new Person();
String firstName = person.getFirstName();
```

It gives me a null value because it creates a new instance. How do I access the property without declaring a new instance?

Thanks

EDIt: Can some one tell me about adding a bean into the Session. THanks

Comment: You would have to pass the existing person to the separate controller.  I think they implemented some way to do it in Spring 3.1, or maybe 3.2, but my memory escapes me on what they call it.  But, what you are doing is creating a new Person, which would have null values in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, CodeChimp. I knew the new instance creates properties with null values. I need a way to know how to access those properties without creating a new instance. I have tried using @Autowired but it still does not work. I cannot really pass this object from one controller to another controller..

Comment: Well, if the Controller lives in the same server, you can use Session to move things around.  I think the other thing I was thinking of is called "Flash Attributes", but you only need those if you are trying to do a forward or redirect, I think.  According to this it's part of 3.1: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: I don't understand the question: why are you creating a new instance if you don't want a new instance?

Comment: I don't want to create a new instance. But how do I access the properties of that class(Form Bean) without creating a new one? One of the ways I found out was to use a session scope. But I am not sure how to use it